# Computer system architecure exam question help me

Tags: cpu-architecture

Assume that a computer architect has already designed 6 two address and 30 zero address instructions using the instruction length of 11 bits and size of the address field of 4 bits. The maximum number of one address instruction that can be added to the instruction set is:

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer progamming question. It is a computer architecture question, perhaps better suited to cs.stackexchange.com. But really, this is just a math question.)

Comment: Note also that it is probably a violation of academic honesty rules to obtain outside assistance with exam questions. (At a minimum, you need to cite your sources.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an address field of 4 bits, a 2-address opcode has 8 bits of address; thus 3 bits  (11 - 2*4) to specify the opcode.  Note that because the 8 address bits can have any value, one of these 3 bit opcodes must be reserved for specifying 0 or 1 address opcodes.   6 were already defined, so 2^3 - (6 + 1) is the number of available 2-address opcodes.

That leaves 8 bits to encode the zero and one address opcodes.
1 bit can be used to discriminate; leaving 7 bits for zero address opcodes,
and 7-4 bits for one address opcodes.

So, the total available opcode space is (2^3 - (6 + 1)) + (2^7 - 30) + (2^(7-4)).

That should be more than enough clarity for you to work out the answer.

Comment: You're working too hard. There is no requirement that the instruction encoding be sane. There are 2^11 possible encodings. 6 * 2^4 * 2^4 are used by 2-address instructions. 30 are used by zero-address instructions. Subtraction tells you how many are left to encode 1-address instructions.

Comment: Each one-address opcode costs 16 encodings.